# set thetamin with polar scatter plot in python 2.7.13

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to reproduce this plot here:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#scatter-plot-on-polar-axis-confined-to-a-sector

Copying exactly the code from there. 
But, then it gives me this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "polar_scatter.py", line 57,
>   in 
>       ax.set_thetamin(45) AttributeError: 'PolarAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_thetamin'

I'm using version 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the example you linked above using Matplotlib 2.1.1 and it worked perfectly fine.

I'm pretty sure the `ax.set_thetamin()` option was added to matplotlib in a reasonably recent update, so I think you want to make sure you have a recent version of Matplotlib available. Have a look at the Anaconda instructions on [managing packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) to learn how to do that.

Hope that helps!